# Push items to fluent ui commandbar component

Tags: reactjs, office-ui-fabric, fluent-ui, fluentui-react

I am using the fluent UI command bar component. When I try to push additional items to the _items array after the initial render, the command bar adds them as overflow items in the clickable ellipsis at the end of the command bar. If the condition is met and they are pushed before the initial render, they render properly, as normal command bar items. How do I make them render properly if they are pushed after the initial render?

```
const _items: ICommandBarItemProps[] = [
      {
        key: 'send',
        text: 'Send',
        iconProps: { iconName: 'Send' },
        onClick: (e) => {action('send', editableValues, null, dispatch, data.id)},
      },
      {
        key: 'save',
        text: 'Save',
        iconProps: { iconName: 'Save' },
        onClick: (e) => {asn('save', editableValues, null, dispatch, data.id, index)},
      },

      {
        key: 'history',
        text: 'History',
        iconProps: { iconName: 'History' },
        onClick: (e) => {asn('hist', editableValues, null, dispatch, data.id)},
      },
];
```

// items I want to push

```
if (some condition is met) {
  const _additional_items: ICommandBarItemProps[] = [
     {
         key: 'download',
         text: 'Download',
         iconProps: { iconName: 'Download' },
         onClick: (e) => {asn('down', editableValues, null, dispatch, data.id)},
     },{
         key: 'print',
         text: 'Print',
         iconProps: { iconName: 'Print' },
         onClick: (e) => {asn('prnt', editableValues, null, dispatch, data.id)}
     }
  ]
  _items.concat(_additional_items)
}
```

// here is my basic command bar implementation

```
 <CommandBar
    items={_items}
    ariaLabel="Use left and right arrow keys to navigate between commands"
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to add

```
<CommandBar
    items={_items}
    ariaLabel="Use left and right arrow keys to navigate between commands"
    onReduceData={()=>undefined}   
/>
```

Referred from [CommandBar](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/fluentui#/controls/web/commandbar)

Comment: I'm not working with this library anymore... if anyone wants to validate that it works... I'm happy to mark it as the correct answer! Thanks for answering.